# Change filename in array with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have the this array

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [value] => /4/9/492.jpg
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [value] => /4/9/493.jpg
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [value] => /4/9/494.jpg
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [value] => /4/9/495.jpg
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [value] => /w/i/witbox_schwarz.jpg
    )

)
```

I would like to change the values with a new filename following this scheme.

```
$n = count($arr);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    if ($key == $i) {
      echo 'old filename is ' . $value . ' ... new filename will be ' . $prod_result['products_id'] . '_' . $key . '.' . pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
    }
  }
}
```

Everything is fine but I don't get the old value from the array within my foreach loop.

Comment: No this is a visualization just for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i done in my system this works perfectly

```
$arr = [0 => ['value' => "/4/9/492.jpg"],1 => ['value' => "/4/9/493.jpg"],2 => ['value' => "/4/9/494.jpg"],3 => ['value' => "/4/9/495.jpg"],4 => ['value' => "/w/i/witbox_schwarz.jpg"]];


$n = count($arr);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    if ($key == $i) {
      echo 'old filename is ' . $value['value'] . ' ... new filename will be ' . $prod_result['products_id'] . '_' . $key . '.' . pathinfo($value['value'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
    }
  }
}
```